# Retrieve Google Docs document list

Tags: android, google-docs, authentication

I managed to get an auth token from the AccountManager on Android for "writely" (Google Docs).
Now I want to get all documents from the user - but I have absolutley no idea how to do this. 
There are a lot of libraries out there including the Google-Api-Java-Client but I have no clue how to use them. The picasa sample app also dosent help me... :(
Anyone, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Document List API V3 is what you can use - For details of using it and what to do with OAuth token etc take a look at [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/)

[DocService's JavaDocs](https://developers.google.com/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/client/docs/DocsService)

```
 DocsService service = new DocsService("test-docs-service");
service.setOAuthCredentials(oauthParameters, new OAuthHmacSha1Signer());

try {
    DocumentListFeed feed = service.getFeed(new URL("https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full"), DocumentListFeed.class);
    if(null != feed || feed.getEntries().size() > 0){
        System.out.println("feed size = " +feed.getEntries().size());
        for(DocumentListEntry entry : feed.getEntries())
        {
            System.out.println("filename = "+entry.getTitle().getPlainText());
        }
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("feed null OR size <=0");
    }
} catch (ServiceException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are several sample projects at the Google Code project of google-api-java-client [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse?repo=samples)

Specifically for Android there are Calendar, Picasa and Tasks samples but there is also a Google Docs sample for command line Java. I would think it can be easily ported to Android.

Comment: I have no idea what to do with my auth token. Where shall this token be send to? http://what-google-url.com/?token=here